# in Zend Framework 2 or 3, can module name be same as class name?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, naming

We would like to create a module for our project called `Memcached`. This way we can have namespaced services (e.g. `Memcached\Service\Get`) which perform actions using php's installed `Memcached` class.

However, we notice the following lines in `zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ModuleResolverListener.php`

```
if (class_exists($moduleName)) {
    return new $moduleName;
}
```

This means that if we name our module `Memcached`, then loading the module simply will not work. The module will be instantiated as a  `Memcached` object rather than the desired `Memcached\Module` object.

So, is there any way we can simply name our module `Memcached`? Or, do we need to be more creative and name our module something like `MemcachedModule`? We would prefer not to do the latter since none of our other modules have this `Module` suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework 3 has been patched so that a module may be named the same as an existing class. The following code was added to the `ModuleResolverListener`:

```
$class = sprintf('%s\Module', $moduleName);
if (class_exists($class)) {
    return new $class;
}
```

So now, for example, we can create our own Zend Module called `Memcached\Module` which will not conflict with php's built in `Memcached` class.

For more info, [view the patch on GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/commit/d6ae1b4c5ac7a298ee304b4090c3f27b889975fc).

Answer (score -1):

Module is Zend thing written using PHP Classes. You cant have two classes with same name, so you also cant import "module class" and "own class" with same name, but this is related only if you working in one namespace. You can access classes by full namespace. Here is some example.

```
<?php
namespace my\space;

class TheOne {
   function __construct() {
       print "my one created\n";
   }
}

namespace other\space;
use my\space\TheOne as MyOne;

class TheOne {
   function __construct() {
       print "other one created\n";
   }
}

new TheOne(); //other one created
new MyOne();  //my one created
```